# Set folder permission for user in Sharepoint 2013 using Rest API from .Net without Sharepoint environment?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, sharepoint, office365api

How to set folder permission for user in Sharepoint 2013 using Rest API from .Net with out Sharepoint environment?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the demo below:

[Break Inheritance And Add Role Permissions Using REST API In SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fc34aa/break-inheritance-and-add-role-permissions-using-rest-api-in/)